# Python вычислить квадрат арксинуса от аргумента X

Tags: python, математика

Хочу вычислить квадрат арксинуса от аргумента X

```
from math import pow, asin
pow(asin, 2)(x)
```

**но я понимаю, что это не работает, потому что pow вернет число**

Comment: Можете недопонимаю, а что вы ожидаете на выходе?

Answer (score 1):

Ну как в школе на алгебре - сначала вычисляем арксинус от X, потом результат возводим
в квадрат

```
y = pow(asin(x), 2)
```

ещё в степень можно возвести с помощью оператора `**`

```
y = (asin(x))**2
```